# When running my django project in python3 manage.py run server i get this error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.urllib3.connection'

Tags: python, django, pip, manage.py

After i run python3 manage.py runserver i get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 11, in main
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
File "/Users/luiseduardo/Practice/nova/nova_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 12, in 
from django.conf import settings
ImportError: cannot import name 'settings' from 'django.conf' (unknown location)

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 13, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
(nova_venv) Luiss-MacBook-Pro:novadjango luiseduardo$ pip install django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/luiseduardo/Practice/nova/nova_venv/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/Users/luiseduardo/Practice/nova/nova_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/Users/luiseduardo/Practice/nova/nova_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/Users/luiseduardo/Practice/nova/nova_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .connection import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.urllib3.connection'
```

Im using mac and i do have my virtualenv activated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this solved for me: `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Thank you Joao. I ended up cloning a previous branch and creating a new project since nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to virtual env by following command:
`.\<your virtual env name>\Scripts\activate`

and type `pip list`. If you didn't saw django, please install django by: `pip install django`

If you still get this error or new one please edit post and put your setting.py source. Thanks